# how do i declare an array in a struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization

i did this code. I tried declaring the array in the struct as well. but i keep on getting an error message. Can someone help me :) Thank you. Have a nice day.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct stack
{
    int arr[5];
    int top;
}st;


void push (int ele)
{
    st.arr[st.top]=ele;
    st.top++;
}
int pop()
{
    int item=st.arr[st.top];
    st.top--;
    return item;
}
void display()
{
    int i;
    for(i=4;i>=0;i--)
    {
        printf("%d\t",st.arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
   st.arr[5]={3,6,8,7,5};
   display();
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error msg.

Comment: you have to declare `struct stack st;` in main first before you can use it for any other purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
st.arr[5]={3,6,8,7,5};
```

Because you can't assign directly to a whole array at once.  What you can do however is initialize the struct along with the array it contains at the point it is defined:

```
struct stack
{
    int arr[5];
    int top;
} st = { {3,6,8,7,5}, 5};
```

Comment: i did like you said. but when i use the pop function , It displays "Deleted element =5' even though it should be 9.                                                                                                        ```#include<stdio.h>
struct stack
{
    int arr[5];
    int top;
}st = { {3,6,8,7,9},5};



int pop()
{
    int item=st.arr[st.top];
    st.top--;
    return item;
}
int main()
{

    printf("deleted element = %d\n",pop());
    push(66);
    display();

}```

Comment: ooh...Ok. Thank you so much... Have a nice day!

Comment: My earlier comment (about the initialization value) is wrong, I had not taken a close look at your code. You should keep the initialized value at 5, and adjust your `pop()` function as follows (for example): `int pop() { if (st.top) { return st.arr[--st.top]; } return -1; }` return value of -1 is for just for illustration.

Comment: Sure . :) Thanks again